# WSDL error on translating SOAP client from PHP5 to PHP4/nuSOAP

Tags: php, soap, nusoap, porta-one

Alright, I'm tired of racking my brain on this, so hopefully someone here can enlighten me:

I'm trying to access a SOAP service using PHP and nuSOAP.  While I have successfully accessed the service using PHP5's built-in SoapClient, I am unfortunately limited to PHP4, and using nuSOAP; resulting in a WSDL error that I can't figure out.

The PHP5 code (works):

```
   $wsdl= 'https://mybilling.hipointinc.com:8443/wsdl.fcgi?get=Session.xsd';
   $soap_client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));

   $args = array("login" => $account_id, "password" => $password, "domain" => $domain);
   $session = $soap_client->login($args);
```

The nuSOAP code (doesn't work):

```
   $wsdl= 'https://mybilling.hipointinc.com:8443/wsdl.fcgi?get=Session.xsd';
   $namespace = 'https://mybilling.hipointinc.com/UM/SOAP/Session';
   $soap_client = new soapclient($wsdl, true, null, $namespace);

   $args = array("login" => $account_id, "password" => $password, "domain" => $domain);
   $session = $soap_client->call('login', array($args));
```

This returns the following error:

```
  wsdl error: http://schemas.portaone.com/soap:LoginRequest (LoginRequest) is not a supported type.
```

Why does the PHP5 version work, while the nuSOAP version doesn't?  I'm sure it just something stupid I've overlooked, but I would appreciate some help.

For more info, I'm using the Porta Switch, PortaBilling XML API: [documentation](http://portaone.com/resources/docs/PortaSwitch/m-r-28/PortaSwitch_Interfaces_MR28.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after exploring this some more, I finally came to the answer: I had to upgrade the version of the nuSOAP library I was using.  Turns out I had an older version, and simply updating that version resolved the problem (Sigh) I knew it was something stupid, but for any of you future coders who happen upon this thread via google: Learn from my mistake, and make sure the resources you are using are up-to-date.